# Binding consecutive keypresses to separate actions in Hammerspoon

Tags: keybindings

I am trying to achieve the following scenario in Hammerspoon:

- when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (and no other key is pressed within 300
  ms) => launch Finder
- when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and then again
  another <kbd>E</kbd> within 300 milliseconds => launch Excel, without launching
  Finder

How do I achieve this?

I tried several tricks with `hs.hotkey.bind` along with boolean flags and `hs.timer`, but not got a solution to this yet. Also tried `hs.hotkey.modal`, without success.

Any help towards a solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance!